# Run condition in GAE datastore

Tags: python, google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore

```
class ModelCount(db.Model):
    type = db.StringProperty(required=True,default='Default-type') 
    count = db.IntegerProperty(required=True, default=0) #Current counter

    def to_dict(self):
       d = dict([(p, unicode(getattr(self, p))) for p in self.properties()])
       d["id"] = self.key().id()
       return d

    #Increments counter
    @staticmethod
    def increment_counter(en_name):
         modelCount = ModelCount.all().filter('type',en_name).get()
         if modelCount:
            modelCount.count += 1
            modelCount.put()
         else:
            modelCount = ModelCount(type=en_name, count=1)
            modelCount.put()
```

In the above code (`increment_counter`), I am reading the count from `ModelCount` and incrementing it by one. I face run condition in `increment_counter` method when the server receives multiple requests. So I want to make `increment_counter` atomic. If I use  `@db.transactional` on `increment_counter`, I get "Only ancestor queries are allowed inside transactions" error.

How can I fix this and make it atomic?

Comment: You should *avoid* atomicity; the GAE gives you *eventual consistency*, not an atomic data storage.

Comment: But in my case I want to preserve consistency. How can I achieve it? Do I need to use locks?

Comment: You cannot, not reliably. And you'll kill any and all performance in any case, as you'll have to wait for your data to be replicated across the vast Google network of datacenters around the world.

Comment: You can get [strong consistency if you use a parent key](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/datastore/structuring_for_strong_consistency) but then you're limited in the rate you can write.

Comment: Why do you feel you need a precise count in the first place? You may want to move to using [Cloud SQL](https://developers.google.com/cloud-sql/) instead.

Comment: We are creating an id based on this count. So due to the race condition we are getting two records with same id

Comment: Then don't use ids based on count. Use UUIDs or other randomized values instead.

Comment: Or just the automatic datastore key id..

Comment: Thanks Martijn and Daniel

Comment: @MartijnPieters if I use [UUID](https://docs.python.org/2/library/uuid.html) will there be any UUID collisions after I restart the server?

Comment: There will be no collisions. Or rather, there *may* be a collision once every few million years..... Does your application have to last that long?

Answer (score 1):

you could try to use sharding https://developers.google.com/appengine/articles/sharding_counters

full source available at https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/appengine-sharded-counters-python